# Is rvest the best tool to collect information from this table?

Tags: css, r, dynamic, web-scraping, rvest

I have used rvest package to extract a list of companies and the `a.href` elements in each company, which I need to proceed with the data collection process. This is the link of the website: http://www.bursamalaysia.com/market/listed-companies/list-of-companies/main-market.

I have used the following code to extract the table but nothing comes out. I used other approaches as those posted in "Scraping table of NBA stats with rvest" and similar links, but I cannot obtain what I want. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

my code:

```
link.main <- 
 "http://www.bursamalaysia.com/market/listed-companies/list-of-companies/main-market/"

web <- read_html(link.main) %>% 
html_nodes("table#bm_equities_prices_table") 
    # it does not work even when I write html_nodes("table") 
    or ".table" or #bm_equities_prices_table

web <- read_html(link.main) 
        %>% html_nodes(".bm_center.bm_dataTable") 
  # no working

web <- link.main %>% read_html() %>% html_table() 
  # to inspect the position of table in this website
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The page generates the table using JavaScript, so you either need to use `RSelenium` or Python's Beautiful Soup to simulate the browser session and allow javascript to run.

Another alternative is to use awesome package by @hrbrmstr called `decapitated`, which basically runs headless Chrome browser session in the background.

```
#devtools::install_github("hrbrmstr/decapitated")

library(decapitated)
library(rvest)

res <- chrome_read_html(link.main)

main_df <- res %>% 
  rvest::html_table() %>%
  .[[1]] %>%
  as_tibble()
```

This outputs the content of the table alright. If you want to get to the elements underlying the table (`href` attributes behind the table text), you will need to do a bit more of list gymnastics. Some of the elements in the table are actually missing links, extracting by css proved to be difficult.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

href_lst <- res %>% 
  html_nodes("table td") %>% 
  as_list() %>% 
  map("a") %>% 
  map(~attr(.x, "href"))

# we need every third element starting from second element
idx <- seq.int(from=2, by=3, length.out = nrow(main_df))

href_df <- tibble(
  market_href=as.character(href_lst[idx]),
  company_href=as.character(href_lst[idx+1])
)

bind_cols(main_df, href_df)

#> # A tibble: 800 x 5
#>       No `Company Name`   `Company Website` market_href   company_href
#>    <int> <chr>            <chr>             <chr>         <chr>       
#>  1     1 7-ELEVEN MALAYS~ http://www.7elev~ /market/list~ http://www.~
#>  2     2 A-RANK BERHAD [~ http://www.arank~ /market/list~ http://www.~
#>  3     3 ABLEGROUP BERHA~ http://www.gefun~ /market/list~ http://www.~
#>  4     4 ABM FUJIYA BERH~ http://www.abmfu~ /market/list~ http://www.~
#>  5     5 ACME HOLDINGS B~ http://www.suppo~ /market/list~ http://www.~
#>  6     6 ACOUSTECH BERHA~ http://www.acous~ /market/list~ http://www.~
#>  7     7 ADVANCE SYNERGY~ http://www.asb.c~ /market/list~ http://www.~
#>  8     8 ADVANCECON HOLD~ http://www.advan~ /market/list~ http://www.~
#>  9     9 ADVANCED PACKAG~ http://www.advan~ /market/list~ http://www.~
#> 10    10 ADVENTA BERHAD ~ http://www.adven~ /market/list~ http://www.~
#> # ... with 790 more rows
```

Comment: This was very useful! I am curious about this decapitated function. I would like to ask you how to apply your solution, but in a situation in which I want to extract table from multiple pages.  The link ( http://www.bursamalaysia.com/market/listed-companies/list-of-companies/main-market) just change across pages by adding 'page' + number of the page to 100

Answer (score 1):

Another option without using browser:

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
library(XML)
r <- httr::GET(paste0(
    "http://ws.bursamalaysia.com/market/listed-companies/list-of-companies/list_of_companies_f.html",
    "?_=1532479072277",
    "&callback=jQuery16206432131784246533_1532479071878",
    "&alphabet=",
    "&market=main_market",
    "&_=1532479072277"))
l <- rawToChar(r$content)
m <- gsub("jQuery16206432131784246533_1532479071878(", "", substring(l, 1, nchar(l)-1), fixed=TRUE)
tbl <- XML::readHTMLTable(jsonlite::fromJSON(m)$html)$bm_equities_prices_table
```

output:

```
> head(tbl)
#  No                      Company Name                Company Website
#1  1 7-ELEVEN MALAYSIA HOLDINGS BERHAD      http://www.7eleven.com.my
#2  2                 A-RANK BERHAD [S]        http://www.arank.com.my
#3  3              ABLEGROUP BERHAD [S]       http://www.gefung.com.my
#4  4             ABM FUJIYA BERHAD [S]    http://www.abmfujiya.com.my
#5  5          ACME HOLDINGS BERHAD [S] http://www.supportivetech.com/
#6  6              ACOUSTECH BERHAD [S]   http://www.acoustech.com.my/
```

Comment: You need to mention where to get the link you pasted here. Open Developer Tools in Chrome by pressing Ctrl+Shift+I (F12 on Win). Go to Network tab and inspect the longest running query. Get the Request URL. You should be able to use it immediately in R (although with proper security token should expire pretty fast) https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXHYK.png